# Duplicate data in LEFT Join mysql query

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

may be a duplicate question...
here are two tables **tasks_0_tasks_staff** and **tasks_0_staff_time_management**:

```
tasks_0_tasks_staff

+----+---------+---------+
| id | task_id | user_id |
+----+---------+---------+
|  1 |       1 |     348 |
|  2 |       1 |     350 |
|  3 |       2 |     350 |
|  4 |       2 |     351 |
|  5 |       2 |     357 |
+----+---------+---------+
```

and

```
tasks_0_staff_time_management
+----+---------+---------+-------------+-------+
| id | user_id | task_id | day_of_week | hours |
+----+---------+---------+-------------+-------+
|  1 |     350 |       1 |           2 |     2 |
|  2 |     350 |       1 |           3 |     3 |
+----+---------+---------+-------------+-------+
```

when i execute following query it shows duplicate data in left join table... how can i show null (which is the actual case)...

```
SELECT tasks_0_tasks_staff.`task_id`,
 tasks_0_staff_time_management.day_of_week,
 tasks_0_staff_time_management.hours 

FROM tasks_0_tasks_staff 

LEFT JOIN `tasks_0_staff_time_management` ON `tasks_0_staff_time_management`.`user_id`= `tasks_0_tasks_staff`.`user_id` 

WHERE `tasks_0_tasks_staff`.`user_id`= 350 

ORDER BY `tasks_0_tasks_staff`.`task_id` ;

results:
+---------+-------------+-------+
| task_id | day_of_week | hours |
+---------+-------------+-------+
|       1 |           2 |     2 |
|       1 |           3 |     3 |
|       2 |           2 |     2 |
|       2 |           3 |     3 |
+---------+-------------+-------+
```

why the last two rows in result is showing **day_of_week** and **hours** column values as these don't exists in left join table? how can these two rows shows **NULL** value... ?

i'm expecting the results to be like this

```
+---------+-------------+-------+
| task_id | day_of_week | hours |
+---------+-------------+-------+
|       1 |           2 |     2 |
|       1 |           3 |     3 |
|       2 |        NULL |  NULL |
|       2 |        NULL |  NULL |
+---------+-------------+-------+
```

Comment: This looks perfect for me. I couldn't see any NULL values here.

Comment: use distinct or group by...

Comment: @PraveenKumar im expecting last two rows to show NULL data for day_of_week and hours column... as there is no matching values present in left joined table...

Comment: Shouldn't you be joining on both `userid` and `taskid` in your case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `task_id` as a condition on your join:

```
SELECT tasks_0_tasks_staff.`task_id`,
    tasks_0_staff_time_management.day_of_week,
    tasks_0_staff_time_management.hours 
FROM tasks_0_tasks_staff 
LEFT JOIN `tasks_0_staff_time_management` ON `tasks_0_staff_time_management`.`user_id`= `tasks_0_tasks_staff`.`user_id`  AND `tasks_0_staff_time_management`.`task_id`= `tasks_0_tasks_staff`.`task_id`
WHERE `tasks_0_tasks_staff`.`user_id`= 350 
ORDER BY `tasks_0_tasks_staff`.`task_id` ;
```

Or with some more semantic SQL:

```
SELECT tasks_0_tasks_staff.`task_id`,
    tasks_0_staff_time_management.day_of_week,
    tasks_0_staff_time_management.hours 
FROM tasks_0_tasks_staff 
LEFT JOIN `tasks_0_staff_time_management` USING (`task_id`, `user_id`)
WHERE `tasks_0_tasks_staff`.`user_id`= 350 
ORDER BY `tasks_0_tasks_staff`.`task_id` ;
```

Here's a little proof of concept SQL fiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2a2425/1

Comment: on this line: LEFT JOIN `tasks_0_staff_time_management` USING (`task_id`, `user_id`) , which column are being referred here, task_id and user_id of tasks_0_tasks_staff table OR tasks_0_staff_time_management table ?

Comment: Both. The `using` syntax is handy when both tables share the same column name. It's shorthand for `ON table_a.colname = table_b.colname`. You can list as many columns as you want. Both my examples are the same SQL, just a different way of writing the same join.

Answer (score 2):

You have to change your code like this

```
SELECT tasks_0_tasks_staff.`task_id`,
 tasks_0_staff_time_management.day_of_week,
 tasks_0_staff_time_management.hours 

FROM tasks_0_tasks_staff 

LEFT JOIN `tasks_0_staff_time_management` ON `tasks_0_staff_time_management`.`user_id`= `tasks_0_tasks_staff`.`user_id` 

WHERE `tasks_0_tasks_staff`.`user_id`= 350 AND `tasks_0_tasks_staff`.`task_id` = tasks_0_staff_time_management.`task_id`

ORDER BY `tasks_0_tasks_staff`.`task_id` ;
```

Comment: but just for curiosity... can i get NULL value for task_id = 2... i mean the last 2 rows must show but it show NULL in not found columns...

Comment: You can use FULL OUTER JOIN or FULL JOIN

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a condition in your where so that it only matches records with the same task_id.

Note that duplicate results mean that the different related rows are identical which is **not** your case.

Comment: sorry i'm unable to grab this... how and why mysql is inserting duplicate data... why not it simple putting NULL as...

Comment: Your results are not duplicate.  The task_id column is different.

Comment: i have updated the question... please refer to the bottom-most table of expected results of the query... for task_id= 2, the day_of_week and hours column must show NULL... but mysql is showing duplicated data as in case for task_id= 1...

Comment: You're doing a cartesian join which means that you fail to use proper conditions to match your records together.

Comment: If you want to include rows that don't match, you'd need to use an outer join.

Answer (score 0):

You should use "INNER JOIN" for it.

```
SELECT tasks_0_tasks_staff.`task_id`,
 tasks_0_staff_time_management.day_of_week,
 tasks_0_staff_time_management.hours 

FROM tasks_0_tasks_staff 

INNER JOIN `tasks_0_staff_time_management` ON `tasks_0_staff_time_management`.`user_id`= `tasks_0_tasks_staff`.`user_id` 

WHERE `tasks_0_tasks_staff`.`user_id`= 350 

ORDER BY `tasks_0_tasks_staff`.`task_id` ;
```